# Printing sorted List values in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have 2 lists:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

list1.add("Jonny", "Adam", "Dave");
list2.add("Katie, Toni", "Sam");
```

I want a key for each list, so I define a HashMap:

```
HashMap<Integer, List<String>> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();

hmap.put(1, list1);
hmap.put(2, list2);
```

I've been searching and reading all over and I cannot understand a way to print the key and then all the elements within the list (in order) associated with that key. HashMap does not sort values?

Is there a better way to go about this?

I want to only print values for key=1

Comment: Can you add your expected output? Because I don't quite get it. `hmap.get(1)` gets the list for key `1`. `System.out.println(hmap.get(1))` prints the list associated with key `1`. No, `HashMap` does not hold the entries sorted. `LinkedHashMap` maintains insertion order, `TreeSet` sorts based on the keys.

Comment: Use `LinkedHashMap` to keep entries in insertion order or `TreeMap` to keep entries sorted by key according to either their natural order or a specified `Comparator`. As to each list, you should sort it if you want the elements to be sorted. Use `list.sort()`.

Answer (score 0):

TreeMap keeps order of keys.

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("Jonny", "Adam", "Dave");
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("Katie", "Toni", "Sam");

Map<Integer, List<String>> hmap = new TreeMap<>();

hmap.put(2, list2);
hmap.put(1, list1);

for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> e : hmap.entrySet()) {

    System.out.print("Key : " + e.getKey() + " values: ");
    e.getKey();

    for (String s : e.getValue()) {
        System.out.print(s + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```